# What is installed and uninstalled thrust?

Tags: propulsion

I am reading **Elements of propulsion**.He starts introduction of thrust equations that involve installed and uninstalled thrust.Can somebody please define what uninstalled thrust and installed thrust is?

Comment: I have edited my question and hope that it is now more clear to what I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled thrust is that measured on a test stand under carefully controlled conditions, with no cowlings, covers, fins, flaps, etc. attached.

Installed thrust is that measured with the propulsion unit attached to the vehicle which means any interference with its operation caused by the shape of the cowling, the presence of a wing nearby, the profile of the air intake scoop and the length of the inlet ducting, etc. are represented.

Installed thrust is always less than uninstalled thrust because of the losses caused by that interference.